# How to zoom in Rstudio help window?

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to zoom in the Rstudio help window, it almost kills my eyes, and I can resize the editor font, why they just use the corresponding font?

Comment: You have all the documentation online, you can zoom in as you please there

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202635586-How-to-increase-font-size-in-Help-window-

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I am kind of obsessive-compulsive disorder person, I can't stand with there is a useless window on my ide.